# Criteria sum projection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I try to sum a column, but I get a null pointer exception and I don't know what I do wrong.

```
ChartVentaVendedores chart = new ChartVentaVendedores();
Criteria facturas = getSession().createCriteria(Factura.class);
facturas.add(Restrictions.like("estado", "CONFIRMADO"));
facturas.add(Restrictions.between("fechaCreacion", fromDate, toDate));

Criteria vendedorFactura = facturas.createCriteria("idVendedor");
vendedorFactura.add(Restrictions.eq("idUsuario", idVendedor));
facturas.setProjection(Projections.sum("total"));

Long counter = (Long) facturas.uniqueResult();
int value = counter.intValue();
chart.setValue(counter.intValue());            
chart.setDate(fromDate);
```

Even if I didn't do the join, I still get the `null`.

I tried to change the type of `Long counter = (Long) facturas.uniqueResult();` to `BigInteger` but I still get the same error.

My class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "factura")
public class Factura implements Serializable {

    private int idFactura;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private String estado;
    private Usuarios idVendedor;
    private Date fechaCreacion;
    private Date fechaModificacion;
    private Integer usuarioCreacion;
    private Integer usuarioModificacion;
    private BigInteger total;
    private String tipoFactura;

    ....
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you have specific data in database?

Comment: yeap, i have another function like that, but it do a row count, and it's working fine with the date on my db.

Comment: I think, that your `Projections.sum("total")` can't sum BigIntegers as they don't have autoboxing. Your another function sum BigIntegers?

Comment: nope, my another function just do a row count, as you said, i try changing the type of BigInteger to int, and now it's working. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that your `Projections.sum("total")` can't sum `BigInteger` as it doesn't have autoboxing.

If you can, try change `BigInteger` to `Integer` or `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this to sum up ID of cities in a h2 db, sums up as required.

```
Criteria vendedorFactura = HibernateUtil.getSession().createCriteria(City.class);
        vendedorFactura.add(Restrictions.eq("name", city.getName()));
        vendedorFactura.setProjection(Projections.sum("id"));
        Long counter = (Long) vendedorFactura.uniqueResult();
        System.out.println("Counter:"+counter);
```

`Counter:1161 ( Sum of 1     33 65 97 129 161 193 225 257)`